# Sorting salaries and employees from two arrays

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, swap, bubble-sort

I'm making a really simple sorting program to practice bubble sorting/swap routine. I'm having a problem with this code that I cannot for the life of me figure out. I would appreciate any criticism and help with making this code work and helpful tips to better my knowledge in Python sorting. Thank you everyone.

Purpose of script: Sort in descending order employees + earnings.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Bar/Desktop/IS115/A8.py", line 28, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/Bar/Desktop/IS115/A8.py", line 25, in main
    bubblesort(earnings, names)
  File "C:/Users/Bar/Desktop/IS115/A8.py", line 17, in bubblesort
    swap(A, first, second, E)
  File "C:/Users/Bar/Desktop/IS115/A8.py", line 3, in swap
    temp2 = E[x]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

## Start Code

```
def swap(A, x, y, E):
    temp1 = A[x]
    temp2 = E[x]
    A[x] = A[y]
    E[x] = E[y]
    A[y] = temp1
    E[y] = temp2


def bubblesort(A, E):
    for i in range(len(A)):
        for k in range(len(A) - 1):
            first = k
            second = k + 1

            if (A[first] > A[second]):
                swap(A, first, second, E)
        print(A)
        temp = input("Hit enter for the next step:\n")

def main():
    names = ["Albert, Andy, Bill, Carl, David, Edward, Frank, George, Harry"]
    earnings = [92300, 94200, 81800, 75400, 61300, 53900, 41200, 32300, 29400]

    bubblesort(earnings, names)


main()
```

Comment: Currently, your `names` list only has a single element. You need to place more quotation marks. Or do `names = names[0].split(', ')`.

Comment: Holy crap how did I miss that.